# How best to block ads on non rooted phone?

Tags: applications, ads

How can you block ads on a non rooted phone. I tried rooting and have no success.

Comment: See Izzy's list of [ad blockers](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/network_adblocker). I use Adguard, it's excellent but paid. You can see other alternatives in the list

Comment: Ill look for its alternatives

Comment: Hotwav hot 5th is what i was working with

Answer (score 4):

Adguard is a good option (as suggested above) given it can employ more than one way of filtering ads from traffic. It can utilise local VPN or local HTTP proxy, but can have significant battery drain.

A more lightweight option may be using DNS66, an open source application available for free on the [F-Droid Repository](https://f-droid.org/repository/browse/?fdid=org.jak_linux.dns66).

> DNS66 uses DNS level filtering to filter ad traffic. This means that
>   it only filters the ad traffic for a specific amount of time after
>   your device is connected to the internet. Therefore there will not be
>   any significant battery drain when you are using DNS66 to block ads
>   across the system of your Android device.

After installing, head to the **Hosts** tab at the top of the screen. From here, you'll have to pick at least one ad-blocking hosts file, which is basically a list of known ad servers that DNS66 will block for you.

[image]

Now you have to select the hosts file which contains the list of popular ad servers that are hosting the ads you see across the websites and apps.

The most recommmended one is  *Adaway hosts* (as it covers most popular ad servers) and then click on the Action option and select deny. This will now block all the ads that are hosted by the servers in the Adaway host file’s list.

From here, head back to the Start tab from the top menu, then tap the "Start" icon near the bottom of the screen to start the VPN ad-blocking service.

acknowledgements

- [Block Ads in All Your Android Apps Without Root or Extra Battery Drain](https://android.gadgethacks.com/how-to/block-ads-all-your-android-apps-without-root-extra-battery-drain-0174614/)

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to keep your phone not rooted you still have several options.

- use ad block apps on your phone
- install AdBlock chrome extension for android
- configure your router to block specific sites (not all of them has this feature)
- deploy your own proxy to block what you want

I've been in similar situation before and figured out that the best option for me it the 4th one. So I created a pre-configured squid image deployed in docker on raspberry pi, opened the port on my router and set RPI external ip address as proxy. Since then I have no ads on my phone, not on any site not in the apps and I don't have to worry about privacy because I manage the proxy.

The docker image, its source code and a short documentation are available here: https://github.com/andrassebo/squid-adblock

Comment: Curious about "install AdBlock Chrome extension for Android", considering that Chrome for Android doesn't support browser extensions.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out, it's not a traditional extension (like on PC). But here is one from many: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.adblockplus.adblockplussbrowser